# How do I add Meta Descriptions for Shopify Blog?

Tags: seo, blog, tags, shopify

I'm trying to add Meta Descriptions for my Shopify website in the following urls:

[image: How to add meta to these types of shopify links?]

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Generally, one would insert in their html code  `<meta name="description" content="insert description here">"` but since you're using shopify, the correct method may require tweaking of their software. As this is a website troubleshooting based question tied to a specific small platform your best answer is to read the manual the platform comes with or contact their support, I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: Shopify isn't a small platform. There are at least 300k users who could potentially benefit from an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

This may be different depending on the theme, but the default "liquid" theme has a Meta Description field for Pages, Products, & Blog Articles. There's even a friendly character counter to help keep it a reasonable length.

[image: Shopify Meta Description]

It may not work for blog tags, but those are arguably less important as they're less relevant in SERPs.